# Logging output in Docker Quickstart Terminal

Tags: windows, logging, docker

I want to log all the outputs in [Docker Quickstart Terminal](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/) to a file. How can I do this?

I've tried using [ConEmu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/)'s [Log console output(*)](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsFeatures.html) feature by attaching ConEmu to Docker Quickstart Terminal; but this feature just generates an empty ConEmu-YYYY-MM-DD-pNNNN.log file, which seems to be a bug of ConEmu.

Are there any other ways to log the output in Docker Quickstart Terminal?

Comment: What do you want to log, the output of your containers, or the things you type in the terminal? What's your use-case?

Comment: I wish I could log both the output of my container and the things I type in the terminal.

Comment: to output logs from a container do ... docker logs -f containerName ... this assumes that the container is logging something. For example, this will work if the last point in your ENTRYPOINT script is ... tail -f somefile